# Локализация Angular приложения

Tags: angular, i18n

Есть ангуляр приложение, которое находится на начальной стадии разработки. Необходимо внедрять возможность локализации приложения. Почитав и ознакомившись с потенциально возможными инструментами пришла к выводу, что для крупных проектов лучше использовать `i18n`.
В целом к библиотеки никаких вопросов нет, но не совсем понимаю как пользователь может изменять при необходимости локализацию приложения?

Ведь локализация определяется при генерации приложения через указания параметра в `--configuration`

Comment: Деплоится по копии приложения для каждого перевода. В итоге юзер открывает `domen/ТУТ_ЯЗЫК_ПЕРЕВОДА`, например `http://test.test/ru/`,  `http://test.test/en/`. Вот тут можете посмотреть пример реализации: https://dont-play-with-google.com/

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, отлично спасибо!